# Не получается вывести дату из Базы Данных в формате "Вчера, Сегодня" через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

не могу вывести дату в формате "Вчера/Сегодня" из **БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ**
Обратите внимание на слово "Базы данных"
Сам код:

```
function new_time($a) { // преобразовываем время в нормальный вид
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$ndate = date('d.m.Y', $a);
$ndate_time = date('H:i', $a);
$ndate_exp = explode('.', $ndate);
$nmonth = array(
 1 => 'янв',
 2 => 'фев',
 3 => 'мар',
 4 => 'апр',
 5 => 'мая',
 6 => 'июн',
 7 => 'июл',
 8 => 'авг',
 9 => 'сен',
 10 => 'окт',
 11 => 'ноя',
 12 => 'дек'
);

foreach ($nmonth as $key => $value) {
 if($key == intval($ndate_exp[1])) $nmonth_name = $value;
}

if($ndate == date('d.m.Y')) return 'сегодня в '.$ndate_time;
elseif($ndate == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))) return 'вчера в '.$ndate_time;
else return $ndate_exp[0].' '.$nmonth_name.' '.$ndate_exp[2].' в '.$ndate_time;}
```

Нужно вывести сюда, в строку, вернее в
`<span class="film__leftbar_date" itemprop="uploadDate" content="2021-06-09"><?php echo new_time($single["date"]);  ?></span>`
**Вот что показывается на сайте, в базе данных совсем другая дата, а именно 27.06.2021 в формате просто DATE**

ОБНОВЛЕНО:

В базе данных просто дата когда я создал строку, вот... Мне как раз таки нужно вывести эту дату когда создал строку в базе данных в формате "Вчера/Сегодня".

Comment: Что передается первым параметром?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, о, здравствуйте. Вы про что? Про span? Он должен вывести дату когда была добавлена строка в таблице mysql.

Comment: Про функцию ```new_time```, что будет в переменной ```$a``` внутри функции?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, а... ничего, просто параметр. Как записать туда дату из базы данных?

Comment: Хорошо, давайте по другому. В ```$single["date"]``` что находится? В каком формате дата?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, дата из базы данных, а именно "2021-06-27"

Comment: А откуда тогда берется время?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я когда добавляю строку в базу данных, указываю date сам, а $single просто вытаскивает все данные из БД `"SELECT * FROM singles`

Comment: На скриншоте и в функции вы пытаетесь получить время. То есть строка имеет время? Иначе там было бы 00:00.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, в базе данных просто дата когда я создал строку, вот... Мне как раз таки нужно вывести эту дату, когда я создал строку в базе данных в формате "Вчера/Сегодня". Код... я его скопировал, думал работает.

Comment: То есть нужно просто вывести "вчера" "сегодня" "20 июня 2021"?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Да, именно, но чтобы эти даты были выведены из базы данных.

Comment: Понял. Просто скриншот и код путает ибо там выводится еще и время.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, понял, уберу скриншот и добавлю конкретное описание.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Боже............. Можно вас как нибудь отблагодарить? Могу кинуть донат, просто спасли уже второй раз................ Спасибо большое.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
echo(format_date("2021-06-27")); // сегодня
echo(format_date("2021-06-26")); // вчера
echo(format_date("2021-06-25")); // 25 июн 2021

function format_date($date)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
    static $monthsNames =
    [
        '',
        'янв',
        'фев',
        'мар',
        'апр',
        'мая',
        'июн',
        'июл',
        'авг',
        'сен',
        'окт',
        'ноя',
        'дек'
    ];

    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $todaySeconds = strtotime($today);
    $dateSeconds = strtotime($date);

    $dateDiff = $todaySeconds - $dateSeconds;

    if ($dateDiff < 86400)
    {
        return 'сегодня';
    }
    else if ($dateDiff < 172800)
    {
        return 'вчера';
    }
    else
    {
        $month = $monthsNames[date("n", $dateSeconds)];
        $day = date("d", $dateSeconds);
        $year = date("Y", $dateSeconds);

        return "$day $month $year";
    }
}
```

Comment: Работает. Спасибо огроменное.....

Comment: Галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: Отредактировал код, так наверное будет правильнее.